# SQLAlchemy: Recursive hybrid property in a tree node

Tags: python, tree, sqlalchemy, hybrid, self-reference

I've the following self-referential (tree) node, and wish to filter/sort by the calculated properties `uuid_path` and `name_path`:

```
class Node (db.Model):
    id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.Sequence ('node_id_seq'), primary_key=True)

    ###########################################################################

    root_id = db.Column (db.Integer, db.ForeignKey (id, ondelete='CASCADE'),
        index=True)

    nodes = db.relationship ('Node',
        cascade='all, delete-orphan', lazy='dynamic',
        primaryjoin='Node.id==Node.root_id',
        backref=db.backref ('root', remote_side=id))

    ###########################################################################

    _uuid = db.Column (db.String (36), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True,
        name = 'uuid')
    _name = db.Column (db.Unicode (256), nullable=False, index=True,
        name = 'name')

    ###########################################################################

    @hybrid_property
    def uuid (self):
        return self._uuid

    @hybrid_property
    def name (self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name (self, value):
        self._name = value

    ###########################################################################

    def __init__ (self, name, root, mime=None, uuid=None):

        self.root = root
        self._uuid = uuid if uuid else str (uuid_random ())
        self._name = unicode (name) if name is not None else None

    def __repr__ (self):

        return u'<Node@%x: %s>' % (self.id if self.id else 0, self._name)

    ###########################################################################

    @hybrid_property
    def uuid_path (self):
        node, path = self, []
        while node:

            path.insert (0, node.uuid)
            node = node.root

        return os.path.sep.join (path)

    @hybrid_property
    def name_path (self):
        node, path = self, []
        while node:

            path.insert (0, node.name)
            node = node.root

        return os.path.sep.join (path)

    ###########################################################################
```

If I get a `Node` instance `subnode` and execute e.g. `subnode.name_path` then I get correctly e.g. `root/subnode`. But if I try to use `Node.name_path` (for filtering/sorting) then SQLAlchemy complains:

```
Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Node.root has an attribute 'name'.
```

I'm pretty sure I've to introduce something like:

```
class Node (db.Model):

    @hybrid_property
    def name_path (self):
        node, path = self, []
        while node:

            path.insert (0, node.name)
            node = node.root

        return os.path.sep.join (path)

    @name_path.expression
    def name_path (cls):
        ## Recursive SQL expression??
```

But I struggle to get a correct definition for `@name_path.expression` (or `@uuid_path.expression`); it should somehow instruct SQL to deliver the path from the root node down to the node in question.

What I don't understand is why this is required, since I've told SQLAlchemy to iteratively calculate the path values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: the basic task you have here is to come up with the SQL that would do this lookup.   SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to do that, in this case it would likely require using a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and might be out of scope for what a hybrid can do, as you need to alter the whole structure of the SELECT statement here.

Comment: @zzzeek hmmm, does that also mean I cannot instruct SQLAlchemy to filter/sort by `uuid/name_path`? I thought about introducing a function (using a recursive CTE) on the Postgres side to provide `node.uuid/name_path`, but is it then possible to tell SA to filter/sort by such a "fake" hybrid?

Comment: if you can provide the expression you need as a simple WHERE criterion, then a hybrid can do that, yes.

Comment: @zzzeek Thanks for the answer, I'm sorry [still relatively new to SA], but I think don't see it quite yet.. I managed to write the SQL:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4621968

Comment: @zzzeek Now the SQL works, and I tried to integrate it with SQLAlchemy using `func.name_path (cls)` in `@name_path.expression def name_path (cls):` but this did not do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right after tweaking with PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy, I think I've a solution: (1) First, I'd to write the query as a function in SQL, and (2) second provide the correct SQLAlchemy glue:

The SQL part uses a `WITH RECURSIVE` CTE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_path(node)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

WITH RECURSIVE graph (id, root_id, id_path, name_path) AS (
    SELECT n.id, n.root_id, ARRAY[n.id], ARRAY[n.name]
    FROM node n
UNION
    SELECT n.id, n.root_id, id_path||ARRAY[n.id], name_path||ARRAY[n.name]
    FROM node n, graph g
    WHERE n.root_id = g.id)

SELECT array_to_string (g.name_path, '/','.*')
FROM graph g
WHERE (g.id_path[1] = $1.base_id OR g.root_id IS NULL)
AND (g.id = $1.id)

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION name_path(node)
  OWNER TO webed;
```

and the SQLAlchemy side looks like this:

```
class NamePathColumn (ColumnClause):
    pass

@compiles (NamePathColumn)
def compile_name_path_column (element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return 'node.name_path' ## something missing?
```

and

```
class Node (db.Model):

    def get_path (self, field):

        @cache.version (key=[self.uuid, 'path', field])
        def cached_path (self, field):

            if self.root:
                return self.root.get_path (field) + [getattr (self, field)]
            else:
                return [getattr (self, field)]

        if field == 'uuid':
            return cached_path (self, field)
        else:
            return cached_path.uncached (self, field)

    @hybrid_property
    def name_path (self):
        return os.path.sep.join (self.get_path (field='name'))

    @name_path.expression
    def name_path (cls):
        return NamePathColumn (cls)
```

I avoid accessing `Node.name_path` on the DB if I'm on the pure Python side, but probably it would be faster if I would. The only thing I'm still not so sure about is in `compile_name_path_column` I do not consider any of the `element, compiler, **kwargs` parameters, which makes me a little suspicious.

I just cooked this up, after tinkering for about 1.5 days with SA & PG, so it's very much possible that there is still room for improvement. I'd very much appreciate any remarks w.r.t. this approach. Thanks.

Comment: OK for the @expression, to make that more flexible (such as, if you were dealing with `aliased(Node)`), you could alter your @compiles decorator to actually do a `compiler.process()` on the underlying `Table` or `Alias` construct that's referred to by `cls`.   this requires some more savvy so let me see if I can come up with that...

Comment: @zzzeek This is excellent, I was wondering how I could solve the `aliased (Node)` part. ;D Thank you very much! This stuff will soon be implemented in my NoTex project, see https://notex.ch - an rST editor.

Comment: BTW Anybody reading this: the `CREATE FUNCTION name_path(node)` SQL function is not really a performance hero, since the `WITH RECURSIVE` cte would actually deliver the *whole* table with the corresponding path value (if the `WHERE` clause would not just pick the node we're actually interested in). Therefore *repeteadly* calling `name_path(node)` is actually a performance bottleneck (just figured). Although this approach is quite elegant, it has to be discarded for something faster (tinkering around with [materialized] SQL views right now).

Answer (score 0):

I included zzzeek's feedback from his https://gist.github.com/4625858 for the sake of completeness:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ColumnElement ## !!
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy import inspect

class UuidPathColumn (ColumnElement):
    def __init__(self, entity):
        insp = inspect (entity)
        self.entity = insp.selectable

@compiles (UuidPathColumn)
def compile_uuid_path_column (element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "%s.uuid_path" % compiler.process (element.entity, ashint=True)

class NamePathColumn (ColumnElement):
    def __init__(self, entity):
        insp = inspect (entity)
        self.entity = insp.selectable

@compiles (NamePathColumn)
def compile_name_path_column (element, compiler, **kwargs):
    return "%s.name_path" % compiler.process (element.entity, ashint=True)
```

It's important to use `ColumnElement` (and not `ColumnClause`) for this to work; the relevant code can be found at [node.py](https://github.com/hsk81/webed/blob/86b8cedfd08467a37cab40485a4398d3b8f5a703/webed/models/node.py), [name_path](https://github.com/hsk81/webed/blob/393dfefcc8090ed22b1aa4d057ed15e0eb6de72c/webed/models/sql/name_path.sql) and [uuid_path](https://github.com/hsk81/webed/blob/393dfefcc8090ed22b1aa4d057ed15e0eb6de72c/webed/models/sql/uuid_path.sql). This stuff has been implemented with SQLAlchemy 0.8 and PostgreSQL 9.2.