# Adjacency list + Abstract Base Class Inheritance used in relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

Following is a example for Adjacency List + Inheritance. This works as expected but if i try to use it in a another Model `Mammut` as a relationship it throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/py", line 73, in <module>
    exec(compile(__file__f.read(), __file__, "exec"))
  File "../adjacency_list.py", line 206, in <module>
    create_entries(IntTreeNode)
  File "../adjacency_list.py", line 170, in create_entries
    mut.nodes.append(node)
  File "/home/xxx/.buildout/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/dynamic.py", line 304, in append
    attributes.instance_dict(self.instance), item, None)
  File "/home/xxx/.buildout/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/dynamic.py", line 202, in append
    self.fire_append_event(state, dict_, value, initiator)
  File "/home/xxx/.buildout/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/dynamic.py", line 99, in fire_append_event
    value = fn(state, value, initiator or self._append_token)
  File "/home/xxx/.buildout/eggs/SQLAlchemy-0.9.8-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1164, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event
    child_impl.append(
AttributeError: '_ProxyImpl' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The Code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import (Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, create_engine,
                        Float)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (Session, relationship, backref, joinedload_all)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, AbstractConcreteBase


Base = declarative_base()


class Mammut(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mammut"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nodes = relationship(
        'TreeNode',
        backref='mammut',
        lazy='dynamic',
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        #viewonly=True
    )


class TreeNode(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    depth = Column(Integer, default=0)
    data_type = Column(String(50))

    @declared_attr
    def mammut_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('mammut.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        ret = {}
        if cls.__name__ != "TreeNode":
            ret = {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__,
                   'concrete': True,
                   # XXX redundant makes only sense if we use one table
                   'polymorphic_on': cls.data_type}
        return ret

    @declared_attr
    def parent_id(cls):
        _fid = '%s.id' % cls.__name__.lower()
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(_fid))

    @declared_attr
    def children(cls):
        _fid = '%s.id' % cls.__name__
        return relationship(cls.__name__,
                            # cascade deletions
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                            # many to one + adjacency list - remote_side
                            # is required to reference the 'remote'
                            # column in the join condition.
                            backref=backref("parent", remote_side=_fid),
                            # children will be represented as a dictionary
                            # on the "name" attribute.
                            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection(
                                'name'),
                            )

    def get_path(self, field):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.get_path(field) + [getattr(self, field)]
        else:
            return [getattr(self, field)]

    @property
    def name_path(self):
        # XXX there is no way to query for it except we add a function with a
        # cte (recursive query) to our database see [1] for it
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487386/sqlalchemy-recursive-hybrid-property-in-a-tree-node
        return '/'.join(self.get_path(field='name'))

    def __init__(self, name, value=None, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.depth = 0
        self.value = value
        if self.parent:
            self.depth = self.parent.depth + 1

    def __repr__(self):
        ret = "%s(name=%r, id=%r, parent_id=%r, value=%r, depth=%r, " \
            "name_path=%s data_type=%s)" % (
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self.name,
                self.id,
                self.parent_id,
                self.value,
                self.depth,
                self.name_path,
                self.data_type
            )
        return ret

    def dump(self, _indent=0):
        return "   " * _indent + repr(self) + \
            "\n" + \
            "".join([
                c.dump(_indent + 1)
                for c in self.children.values()]
        )


class IntTreeNode(TreeNode):
    value = Column(Integer)


class FloatTreeNode(TreeNode):
    value = Column(Float)
    miau = Column(String(50), default='zuff')

    def __repr__(self):
        ret = "%s(name=%r, id=%r, parent_id=%r, value=%r, depth=%r, " \
            "name_path=%s data_type=%s miau=%s)" % (
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self.name,
                self.id,
                self.parent_id,
                self.value,
                self.depth,
                self.name_path,
                self.data_type,
                self.miau
            )
        return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)

    def msg(msg, *args):
        msg = msg % args
        print("\n\n\n" + "-" * len(msg.split("\n")[0]))
        print(msg)
        print("-" * len(msg.split("\n")[0]))

    msg("Creating Tree Table:")

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = Session(engine)

    def create_entries(Cls):
        node = Cls('rootnode', value=2)
        Cls('node1', parent=node)
        Cls('node3', parent=node)

        node2 = Cls('node2')
        Cls('subnode1', parent=node2)
        node.children['node2'] = node2
        Cls('subnode2', parent=node.children['node2'])

        msg("Created new tree structure:\n%s", node.dump())

        msg("flush + commit:")
        # XXX this throws the error
        mut = Mammut()
        mut.nodes.append(node)
        session.add(mut)
        session.add(node)
        session.commit()

        msg("Tree After Save:\n %s", node.dump())

        Cls('node4', parent=node)
        Cls('subnode3', parent=node.children['node4'])
        Cls('subnode4', parent=node.children['node4'])
        Cls('subsubnode1', parent=node.children['node4'].children['subnode3'])

        # remove node1 from the parent, which will trigger a delete
        # via the delete-orphan cascade.
        del node.children['node1']

        msg("Removed node1. flush + commit:")
        session.commit()

        msg("Tree after save:\n %s", node.dump())

        msg("Emptying out the session entirely, "
            "selecting tree on root, using eager loading to join four levels deep.")
        session.expunge_all()
        node = session.query(Cls).\
            options(joinedload_all("children", "children",
                                   "children", "children")).\
            filter(Cls.name == "rootnode").\
            first()

        msg("Full Tree:\n%s", node.dump())

        # msg("Marking root node as deleted, flush + commit:")
        # session.delete(node)
        # session.commit()

    create_entries(IntTreeNode)
    create_entries(FloatTreeNode)

    nodes = session.query(TreeNode).filter(
        TreeNode.name == "rootnode").all()
    for idx, n in enumerate(nodes):
        msg("Full (%s) Tree:\n%s" % (idx, n.dump()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concrete inheritance can be very difficult, and AbstractConcreteBase itself has bugs in 0.9 which get in the way of elaborate mappings like this from being used.

Using 1.0 (not released, use git master), I can get the major elements going as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine, ForeignKey, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.collections import attribute_mapped_collection
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, AbstractConcreteBase


Base = declarative_base()


class Mammut(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mammut"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nodes = relationship(
        'TreeNode',
        lazy='dynamic',
        back_populates='mammut',
    )


class TreeNode(AbstractConcreteBase, Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        if cls.__name__ == 'TreeNode':
            return None
        else:
            return cls.__name__.lower()

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'polymorphic_identity': cls.__name__, 'concrete': True}

    @declared_attr
    def parent_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey(cls.id))

    @declared_attr
    def mammut_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('mammut.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def mammut(cls):
        return relationship("Mammut", back_populates="nodes")

    @declared_attr
    def children(cls):
        return relationship(
            cls,
            back_populates="parent",
            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('name'),
        )

    @declared_attr
    def parent(cls):
        return relationship(
            cls, remote_side="%s.id" % cls.__name__,
            back_populates='children')


class IntTreeNode(TreeNode):
    value = Column(Integer)


class FloatTreeNode(TreeNode):
    value = Column(Float)
    miau = Column(String(50), default='zuff')

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

session = Session(e)

root = IntTreeNode(name='root')
IntTreeNode(name='n1', parent=root)
n2 = IntTreeNode(name='n2', parent=root)
IntTreeNode(name='n2n1', parent=n2)

m1 = Mammut()
m1.nodes.append(n2)
m1.nodes.append(root)

session.add(root)
session.commit()


session.close()

root = session.query(TreeNode).filter_by(name='root').one()
print root.children
```